If $Q_q(T)$ is hyponormal then prove that $Q_q(T)^{-1}$ is hyponormal!

If $Q_q(T)$ is hyponormal then prove that $Q_q(T)^{-1}$ is hyponormal,
where $Q_q(T)=T^2-2Re(q)T+\vert q\vert^2$ ,where $q$ is a quaternion.

we are given $Q_q$ is hyponormal so $Q_q(T)^*Q_q(T)\ge Q_q(T)Q_q(T)^*\tag{1}$ and we have to prove $(Q_q(T)^*)^{-1}Q_q(T)^{-1 } \ge Q_q(T)^{-1 } (Q_q(T)^*)^{-1}\tag{2}$
Now multiplying in (1) both sides by $(Q_q(T)^*)^{-1}$ from left  and $Q_q(T)^{-1}$ from right,we'll get $I\ge(Q_q(T)^*)^{-1}Q_q(T)Q_q(T)^*Q_q(T)^{-1}$.
But,this not compatible with (2)!
Please help in proving this,i've invested much efforts in this!!

Your equation $I\ge (Q^\ast)^{-1}Q Q^\ast Q^{-1}$ is "compatible" (i.e. logically consistent) with (2), it just doesn't seem to be helping you get there.

We are using the Loewner ordering $\le$. In general, it is true that  $A\ge B$ implies $C^\ast AC\ge C^\ast BC$. You are applying this with $A=Q^\ast Q$ and $B=QQ^\ast$ and $C=Q^{-1}$, but it doesn't seem to help.
What is also true is that if $A,B$ are positive-definite (note semidefinite and invertible implies definite) and self-adjoint then $A\ge B$ implies $B^{-1}\ge A^{-1}$. You can still apply this with your values of $A$ and $B$. (Note the value of $Q$ is not relevant, except that it is invertible.)

:I  tried your approach ,but i'm not getting the desired result...please tell where i'm doing wrong in my OP?

@Antony Show how you tried this approach. What does $B^{-1}\ge A^{-1}$ become if $A=Q^\ast Q$ and $B=QQ^\ast$? Remember the socks-and-shoes rule. I don't think your approach was "wrong" (i.e. invalid), it just wasn't leading you to where you wanted to be.
